# Scrapy spider not terminating with use of CloseSpider extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I have set up a Scrapy spider that parses an xml feed, processing some 20,000 records.

For the purposes of development, I'd like to limit the number of items processed. From reading the Scrapy docs I identified I need to use the [CloseSpider](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.extensions.closespider) extension.

I have followed the guide on how to enable this - in my spider config I have the following:

```
CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT = 1
EXTENSIONS = {
    'scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider': 500,
}
```

However, my spider never terminates - I'm aware that the `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` setting affects when the spider actually terminates (as it will carry on processing each concurrent request), but this is only set to the default of 16, and yet my spider will continue to process all the items.

I've tried using the `CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT` setting instead, but similarly this has no effect.

Here is some debug info, from when I run the spider:

```
2017-06-15 12:14:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: myscraper)
2017-06-15 12:14:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'myscraper', 'CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT': 1, 'FEED_URI': 'file:///tmp/myscraper/export.jsonl', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'myscraper.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['myscraper.spiders'], 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}
2017-06-15 12:14:11 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider']
2017-06-15 12:14:11 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-06-15 12:14:11 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-06-15 12:14:11 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['myscraper.pipelines.MyScraperPipeline']
2017-06-15 12:14:11 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
```

As can be seen, the `CloseSpider` extension and the `CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT` settings are being applied.

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: You can  use CloseSpider Exception to limit the number of items,

Comment: @parik I tried this also - but I wasn't sure where to add it? I added it to my pipeline, but this just seemed to terminate that item - it then proceeded to do the same with each item. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Ok, and for your question, add 
    CONCURRENT_REQUEST = 1 and let me know if it works please

Comment: @parik - I've already tried that I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with a solution helped by parik's answer, along with my own research. It does have some unexplained behaviour though, which I will cover (comments appreciated).

In my spider's `myspider_spider.py` file, I have (edited for brevity):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from myspiders.items import MySpiderItem

class MySpiderSpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = "myspiders"
    allowed_domains = {"www.mysource.com"}
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.mysource.com/source.xml"
        ]
    iterator = 'iternodes'
    itertag = 'item'
    item_count = 0

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        settings = crawler.settings
        return cls(settings)

    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings

    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        if(self.settings['CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT'] and int(self.settings['CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT']) == self.item_count):
            raise CloseSpider('CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT limit reached - ' + str(self.settings['CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT']))
        else:
            self.item_count += 1
        id = node.xpath('id/text()').extract()
        title = node.xpath('title/text()').extract()
        item = MySpiderItem()
        item['id'] = id
        item['title'] = title

        return item
```

This works - if I set `CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT` to 10, it terminates after 10 items are processed (so, in that respect it seems to ignore `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` - which was unexpected).

I commented out this in my `settings.py`:

```
#EXTENSIONS = {
#   'scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider': 500,
#}
```

So, it's simply using the `CloseSpider` exception. However, the log displays the following:

```
2017-06-16 10:04:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (closespider_itemcount)
2017-06-16 10:04:15 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored jsonlines feed (10 items) in: file:///tmp/myspiders/export.jsonl
2017-06-16 10:04:15 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 600,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 8599860,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'closespider_itemcount',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 16, 9, 4, 15, 615501),
 'item_scraped_count': 10,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 8,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 16, 9, 3, 47, 966791)}
2017-06-16 10:04:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (closespider_itemcount)
```

The key thing to highlight being the first line `INFO` and the `finish_reason` - the message displayed under `INFO` is not the one I'm setting when raising the `CloseSpider` exception. It implies it's the `CloseSpider` extension that's stopping the spider, but I know it isn't? Very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  also **CloseSpider** **Exception** to limit the number of items,

just pay attention, 
**CloseSpider** exception is **only supported** in the **spider callbacks**.

as you can see in [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#closespider)

> This exception can be raised from a spider callback to request the
>   spider to be closed/stopped. Supported arguments:

[some examples](http://programtalk.com/python-examples/scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider/)

Comment: I did some more experimenting with this exception, and it's now working - i'm going to post this as answer. It is exhibiting strange behaviour though, which I can't quite explain.

Comment: @BrynJ yes it's strange that CloseSpider extension doesn't close your spider after certains number of items

Comment: added my answer with my observations on the odd behaviour. Your input would be appreciated.

Comment: @BrynJ in setting.py, in  ITEM_PIPELINES, the number of items is more or less than 500?

Comment: It's set to a priority of 500 - but, to be clear, I'm not throwing the `CloseSpider` exception in my pipeline now, it's being thrown in the main exception.